# Remove datagrid template background after click On

Tags: c#, wpf

my WPF datagrid has some datagridtextColumns and one template column . the template column includes Two buttons(Accept Button & Details Button). When I was selecting a row the background of selected row was changed. To solve it I Use style trigger to get rid of background changing.as you see in the Image datagridtextcolumn background is transparent after clicking but the template cell background still changes.

Picture of the issue:
[Picture of the issue:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuoQj.png)

```
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
```

datagrid XAML Code :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TAB1_LivePrograms_list_DGV"   
                              FontFamily="{StaticResource VazirFont}" 
                              FontSize="12" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                              GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"  
                              CanUserAddRows="False" 
                              CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
                              SelectionMode="Single" 
                              Margin="0"
                              ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" 
                              Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                              IsReadOnly="True" 
                              SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
                              MouseLeftButtonUp="TAB1_LivePrograms_list_DGV_MouseLeftButtonUp">
                        <DataGrid.Resources>
                            <Style x:Key="Whithoutgridlines" TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                            </Style>
                            
                        </DataGrid.Resources>
                        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding row_background}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Select" x:Name="TAB1_Col1" Binding="{Binding NID}" Visibility="Collapsed" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn  x:Name="TAB1_Col2" Binding="{Binding OriginalName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn  x:Name="TAB1_Col3" Binding="{Binding PriceCode}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn  x:Name="TAB1_Col4" Binding="{Binding startdate}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn  x:Name="TAB1_Col5" Binding="{Binding ExpirationDate}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn  x:Name="TAB1_Col6" Binding="{Binding Status}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn  x:Name="TAB1_Col7" Binding="{Binding PermittedCount}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn  x:Name="TAB1_Col11" Binding="{Binding UsedCount}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="TAB1_registered" Binding="{Binding registered_Fee}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="TAB1_waitingtopay" Binding="{Binding waiting_to_Pay_Fee}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn  x:Name="TAB1_paid" Binding="{Binding paid_Fee}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn  x:Name="TAB1_total" Binding="{Binding total_Fee}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn  x:Name="TAB1_Col13" Binding="{Binding tracking_status}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="TAB1_Col14" Visibility="Visible" CellStyle="{StaticResource Whithoutgridlines}"  >
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="30,0,30,0">

                                            <Button x:Name="TAB1_DGV1_submit_request_btn"  Margin="10,0,10,0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
                                                            FontFamily="{StaticResource VazirFont}" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold"                                                        
                                                            Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="blue"  >
                                                <Button.Style>
                                                    <Style>
                                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding status_request}" Value="submitted">
                                                                <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                        </Style.Triggers>

                                                    </Style>
                                                </Button.Style>
                                                <mahicon:Microns Kind="TickInline"/>
                                            </Button>
                                            <Button x:Name="TAB1_DGV1_remove_request_btn"  Margin="10,0,10,0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
                                                            FontFamily="{StaticResource VazirFont}" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold"                                                        
                                                            Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="Red"  >

                                                <Button.Style>
                                                    <Style>
                                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding status_request}" Value="empty">
                                                                <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                        </Style.Triggers>

                                                    </Style>
                                                </Button.Style>
                                                <mahicon:Microns Kind="Cancel"/>
                                            </Button>
                                            <Button x:Name="TAB1_DGV1_show_details_btn"  Margin="10,0,10,0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
                                                            FontFamily="{StaticResource VazirFont}" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold"
                                                            Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="DarkGreen"  
                                                              >

                                                <mahicon:EvaIcons Kind="List"/>
                                            </Button>
                                            <Button x:Name="TAB1_DGV1_prices_Update_btn"  Margin="10,0,10,0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
                                                            FontFamily="{StaticResource VazirFont}" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold"                                                                
                                                            Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="Red" Content="Update" >
                                                <Button.Style>
                                                    <Style>
                                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding status_request}" Value="submitted">
                                                                <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding status_request}" Value="empty">
                                                                <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                           
                                                        </Style.Triggers>

                                                    </Style>
                                                </Button.Style>

                                            </Button>



                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

I Updated datagrid style by adding a template style. but it was not usefull

```
                 <Style x:Key="CellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <DataGridCell Background="Transparent"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Can you please show the context and not just a snippet? For somebody that doesn't know what you are doing and how the involved code looks like, this snippet is meaningless. It would also be nice if could try to explain your problem again, please. It's difficult to understand what the problem is. What you have now and what you want.

Comment: Thank you for improving your question. It helps to understand your problem. Where is the trigger defined? I can't find it in the DataGrid XAML.

Comment: Thnaks  for  your recommendation

Answer (score 0):

You probably have defined the triggers in the wrong place.
To disable the selection highlighting you must define the triggers in the `DataGrid.CellStyle`. Always prefer to set the `Background` to `Transparent` instead of `null`. Using `null` can introduce issues with hit-testing.

```xml
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I change Null value to transparent but problem still  exists. I added new part to my code but it was not useful.

Comment: Please read the example carefully. I have not added a *"datagrid style by adding a template style"*. You must set the DataGrid.CellStyle property like I did in the example. Then it will work.

Comment: I did what you said but still nothing :(

Comment: Can you please extend your question and addd the latest version of the DataGrid, please?

Comment: I replaced the image  with a new one  that explains this clearly, I guess.
Thanks

Comment: Please, help me. I asked you to show me your current code for a reason. You asked how to make the row transparent on selection i.e. remove highlight effect. I gave you a working solution. There must be something wrong with your code that prevents the style from being applied. Therefore, I NEED to see your current code to review it. An image of your GUI doesn't help at all. Otherwise I would have asked for an image of your GUI. If don't support me I can't help you. I have posted a correct answer, the rest is your story. Or help me so that I can help you. Let's not waste time, please.